# Capture hotkey in Swing

Tags: java, swing, hotkeys

I want to catch some hotkeys with 2 letter keys like `Ctrl+P,P` (`Ctrl+P` and press `P` without releasing `Ctrl`) but code below doesn't work:

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_P & KeyEvent.VK_P, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK)
//or
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_P | KeyEvent.VK_P, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK)
```

It only captures `Ctrl+P`

Comment: Just a guess, but shouldn't you be getting two different keystrokes, first for `Ctrl+P` and second for `P`?

Comment: @svz, yes but how do I know whether they are pressed as Ctrl+P,P simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

Then you need to use two separate KeyStrokes and catch each KeyStroke separately. For example:

```
KeyStroke p = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('P'); 
KeyStroke control = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control P");
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information.

Comment: what if I press them separately? either P or Ctrl+P?

Comment: are you sure it's 'P' and "control P"? `Ctrl+P,P` == Ctrl+P and P without releasing Ctrl ~~ Ctrl+P 2 times.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Swing does not allow you to enter the "P" a second time without releasing the control key. A KeyEvent will track all the modifier keys (control, alt, shift) and the time another key is entered. So you would need to write some kind of custom code to see if you get two Control+P events generated in a row.